# jQuery Columnizer plugin only working correctly on window resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [jQuery Columnizer plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/), and I'm running into a weird problem. Using 3 columns, I columnize content from a hidden `<div>` into a target `<div>`. It distributes only one paragraph to each of the first two columns and then puts all the remaining paragraphs into the last column.

The strange thing is that it auto-corrects itself when the window is resized.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the target `<div>` resizing since opening a firebug console window also causes it to auto-correct itself.  Setting `lastNeverTallest:true` doesn't seem to do anything.

```html
$('#hidden-about').columnize({ 
    columns: 3, 
    target: '#interiors',
    lastNeverTallest: true,
    doneFunc: function() {
        $('#interiors').css('white-space', 'normal');
        $('#interiors').fadeIn(200);
    } 
});
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Interesting that setting 'buildOnce:true' makes it stay broken. So it seems that it needs to build more than once to render correctly.

Comment: Try setting the default width to the column holder.

Comment: This issue is addressed on Github in [this issue](https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin/issues/122).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that's it's running after the DOM elements are ready by wrapping it appropriately, like this:

```
$(function() {  //document.ready shortcut
  $('#hidden-about').columnize({ ... }); 
});
//or...
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#hidden-about').columnize({ ... }); 
}); 
//or, if it depends on image sizing, make sure they're loaded with window.load
$(window).load(function() {  //runs after images are loaded
  $('#hidden-about').columnize({ ... }); 
});
```

If that doesn't resolve the issue, you can manually invoke the event it's bound to re-rendering on, using [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) like this:

```
$(window).resize();
```